# Char[] in BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, mysql, spring, bcrypt

I have plain text password in char[]. How can I hash this char[] using [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) and store in database. What database datatype to use to store the hashed password (mySQL).

I want to avoid using Strings because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java).

Comment: Even if this fear is not overblown, this may be impractical to implement all the way through the stack. Where do you get the user input from? If it's based on a Servlet API, your data has most likely already been turned into a String.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CharBuffer`:

```
bcrypt.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(myPasswordArray));
```

As for storing it in the database, the method returns a `String` (which should be of if not fixed at least reasonably small length), so this can be stored in a regular `varchar` column.